# What are the benefits of having a jungler?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the point of jungling?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23549/whats-the-point-of-jungling)

In many games you may find your team having a jungler, what are the benefits of having a jungler and not a second duo lane?