# What is the purpose of a jungle, with solo lane top?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the point of jungling?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23549/whats-the-point-of-jungling)

What is the point of a jungle? Why wouldn't you go dual lane top?

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/23549/16007

Answer (score 0):

Having an extra solo lane allows that player and the jungler to get much higher CS scores than they would sharing a lane.  Furthermore, a jungler is good for ganking lanes, which can be incredibly significant in the laning phase of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about CS (Creeps Slain). Every 25 cs is equal to a kill with an assist. So if you went solo and got 150 cs, you would need to go duo and get around 6 kills for a single champion to get the same cs, then your other champion needs to get kills too. on the other hand, your jungler gets cs thats lower the a lane (Stupid jungle buffs) but can gank lanes, gaining more gold, and helping other win their lane.

You give up both a lot of gold, and a lot of lane control, expecially around dragon. If you don't have a jungler, adn they do. They can pretty much take dragon at any time. You also lose smite, so if you go for baron, they can smite steal. NOT a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think if you can zone their top lane from experience and gold, you negate the damage not having a jungle brings to the table. While this is simply theorycrafting, I think deciding not to have a jungle could be the counter to Moscow 5, who simply dominate your jungle regardless. There is no rule that prevents your second top laner to have smite for barron control later, and dragon and lane control can be improved by running teleport. When dragon fight occurs just tele to a ward on bottom. I have found the person who can break the meta and confuse the other team stands a good chance, and right now having a jungle is the meta.

Answer (score 0):

Something they didn't mention is that a jungler is really good for pressuring other lanes. The jungle is used as a tool to get your carry lanes or solo top lane ahead of the other person through ganking. This allows people to really carry a game and give your team an advantage. As well as securing buff with the summoner spell smite which is huge at later times in the game.

Answer (score 0):

While the talk is about CS, it's not really CS that is the key, but rather experience and lost gold in your own jungle.  You can easily have a team that has duo lane top where one is in the "support" role, in other words doesn't get CS.  However, the solo lane provided they can stay alive and not be completely zoned out will have an advantage in levels since they are not sharing experience from minions as they die, and the person who is now jungling instead of in the support role would get the gold in your jungle, this allows your overall team gold to be increased substantially.

Finally, unless one of your lanes carry smite, you would still have the disadvantage of smite meaning the other team gets free dragons/barons.